# How do I rotate a rectangle in x11 / C

Tags: rotation, x11, xlib

Im supposed to develop a game where the user shoots a ball from a cannon. For that I need to be able to rotate the cannon (rectangle) and shoot from different angles. Could you please help me?

Cheers!

```css
    typedef struct _Cannon {
      int x, y, w, h;
    }Cannon;

typedef struct _Ball{
 int itx, ity; //size
 float ix, iy; //position
 float vx, vy; //velocity
 float gr;    //gravity
}Ball;

    Cannon cannon = {60, 400, 114, 33};
Ball ball = {
 0,0,
 cannon.x+cannon.w*0.8,cannon.y+cannon.h/5,
 17.0, 0,
 0.3
 };

    XSetForeground(XApp->getDisplay(), GCAtr->getGC(),
    GCAtr->getColor(2));
    XFillRectangle(XApp->getDisplay(), XApp->getWindow(), GCAtr->getGC(),cannon.x,cannon.y,cannon.w,cannon.h);
    
void calculate()
{
 double dt;
 dt = XApp->getDifTime();
 
 //Calculates the position of the ball
 ball.vy += ball.gr * dt;
 ball.iy += ball.vy * dt;
 ball.ix += ball.vx * dt;
}
```

[Image of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltbmX.png)

Answer (score 1):

`XFillRectangle` only works with axes-parallel rectangles. For an arbitrary rotated rectangle, use `XFillPolygon`.

You will need to calculate coordinates of the vertices of the rotated rectangle yourself. This is not a tutorial on linear transformations in 2D geometry, but briefly, you will need to do this:

1. Start with a rectangle centered at (0,0).
2. Apply rotation by angle *θ* using a rotation matrix

   ```
           cos θ    sin θ 
          -sin θ    cos θ
   ```

   to each of the corners. This will rotate the corners around the origin.
3. Translate by adding the coordinates of where you want the center of your rectangle to be.